# can't access Keyboard class under System.Windows.Input

Tags: c#

I'm working on a simple console app that just show stuff on the screen.

I got into a problem with `System.Windows.Input` classes, I just cant get to them.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

public class KeyboardHandler
{
    public void UseKeyboard() => System.Windows.Input.Keyboard // Its like the class Keyboard not exsit.
}
```

I'm using a librery `TestStack.White` to do some manipulation on a window that I start from my application.

`TestStack.White` itself has a Keyboard class (`White.Core.InputDevices.Keyboard`), but could it be that this class is stopping me from accessing the `System.Windows.Input.Keyboard` class?

Comment: You're using a full path so there will be no namespace conflict between the two Keyboard classes. Can you edit with your using statements? You might be missing a reference.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but you have referenced the PresentationCore.dll, right?

Comment: @Mario nope, I dont even know that dll.

Comment: That's where your Keyboard-class is. Add the reference and it will work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this is a Console Application, you'll need to add a reference to `PresentationCore.dll`.  This assembly will not be referenced by default in a Console Application.

You can see this in the documentation for [`Keyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Input
>
> Assembly:  PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll)

This is one of the main WPF assemblies, and included by default in WPF projects, but not console applications.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all aspects of ```System.Windows.Input.Keyboard``` are contained within _PresentationCore.dll_ !

The ```Modifiers``` enumerable, for example, resides in _WindowsBase.dll_ and adding a reference to only PresentationCore will generate an error ("CS7069: Reference to type 'ModifierKeys' claims it is defined in `WindowsBase` but it could not be found.") - in this case, you also need to add a project COM Reference to WindowsBase.dll _as well_ in order to use ```ModifierKeys```.