# Detect key press in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, console

I want to detect when a key is held in a console for a small learning project I've been working on a bit. I'm a beginner in coding and I've been following Brackey's "How to Program in C# Tutorial" using the .NET framework and I stopped watching the videos a bit on arrays, I need help with this as I want to make a small secret in it for fun, like when they press the down arrow key it would change the background color as long as the button is held. I've seen a lot of other questions like this but I cant understand:

```
using System.Windows.Input;    
if(Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Key.A)) {
```

I tried using these
but it always gave an error that says:

The name 'Keyboard' does not exist in the current context
and
The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context

any solutions?

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Interactive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down)) 
            {
                  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody answered this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065874/9558437

You need to right click on 'reference' in your project explorer -> add a reference, and then select `PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: Sorry im new to stack overflow didnt mean to delete the comment, 
i found a video on how to add a reference so i'll check out that in the meantime, thanks

Comment: Just answered to the last comment, but he deleted it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add system.windows.input to you're references?

Comment: It's already in their code sample.

Comment: This also wouldn't qualify as an answer, even if it weren't in the posted code sample.