Keyboard dosen't exist?
Full error image
I'm trying to use the keyboard class.
Here is my code
using System;
using System.Windows;     // shows this is unnecessary 

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Map
    {
        public string[][] layer { get; set; }
        public int[][] collision { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(ConsoleKey.Spacebar));
            }
        }
    }
}

Screenshot of error
What do I do?
I tried to add using Windows.Input but it's just showing a IDE0005 warning.
I want to use Keyboard.IsKeyDown for my game but yeah

Have you read the entire error message? Especially the part in parentheses.

updated to show full error message

Could you provide more info on: what kind of project this is, what framework you are targeting ? Besides, did you do a search on the issue first ? Here is a similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065783/cant-access-keyboard-class-under-system-windows-input

Sorry im kinda new to all of this but its a consoleapp using only dotnet console in vscode
i dont know how to refrence .dll files and its dot net 8.03

Try this

Add PresentationCore.dll assembly as a reference.
Add WindowsBase.dll assembly as a reference.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I dont know how plz help im using vs code

I'm not using vs code so I don't know how to add these assemblies either. But it seems that your project is a console app. So can you try to use Console.ReadKey() to read keyboard input?

I can but im making a platformer with the console app so i need to read multiple keys at once
